# Session should not expire when file downloading

Tags: java, servlets, session-timeout, servlet-listeners, struts2

When I download a file from my Struts2 application, the session expires  after download the file. This should not happen.

we can set session time out using setMaxInactiveInterval(), but the file size is not constant, the downloading time depends on file size and etc.

could you please provide any solution.

my file download code as follows.

```
InputStream fileInputStream = null;
    File file = null;
    String fileDir = "C:\\CAP\\FileDownload\\file\\";
    String fileName = "SW.zip";
    HttpSession sessio = null;

    try {
        sessio = request.getSession();
        logger.debug("--------------->>>>"+sessio.getMaxInactiveInterval());
        file = new File(fileDir+fileName);
        logger.debug(":::::::::-->"+file.isFile());
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        ServletOutputStream outputStream = null;
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="
          + fileName);
        response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
        outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

        // Copy the contents of the file to the output stream
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        while ((count = fileInputStream.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            outputStream.write(buf, 0, count);
            logger.debug("Count Is : "+count);
        }

        logger.debug("====================compleated the file donlowding ====================");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("ERROR while reading and wring file : "
                + e.getMessage());

    }
```

Comment: How much time does it take to download a file ?

Comment: Why do you need the session to last all the downloading time? Download should be started in another window of the browser, users could then continue to use the application, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `request.getSession(false)` as
`request.getSession()` returns the current Session associated with this request, or if the request does not have a Session, creates one.

So, in your case I believe `request.getSession()` is creating a new `session` which gets destroyed as soon as download completes.

Answer (score 0):

If file size is large enough and time will be beyond to your session time out, then better to user ASynchronise service which download the file side by side and user can continue with his work. Something like Batch.